# Where to write this method in Model or Controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, activerecord

I am new at rails and the more on MVC. So I have a model called Bet, it has attributes: id, odd, description, outcome. I want to write methods `set_won` that would change outcome to `1` and `set_lost` that would change outcome to `0`.

I am not quite sure where to implement these methods in Model or in Controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest that you look into using an enum for this, whereby you set values on your outcome attribute as one of "None", "Won", or "Lost".

An enum will provide you with the getter and setter methods, and scopes for listing all won or lost bets.

http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html

Answer (score 2):

You should write it in the model.

In your controller you'll call an action "BetController#update" or whatever you would like, then do something like this:

```
class BetController < ApplicationController
   ...
   def update
     #do somestuff
     @bet.set_won or @bet.set_lost
   end

  -------

  class Bet < ActiveRecord::Base
    #some stuff up here
    def set_won
      self.outcome = 1
    end

    def set_lost
      self.outcome = 0
    end
  end
```

Comment: why do I need to write self.outcome ? can I write just outcome = 1 and so on? @Menelik Tucker

Comment: Yes you could write `outcome = 1`, both statement are equivalent in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can write this code in Model as it is specific to setting an attribute in Bet Model. Also as Rails has the saying "Fat Model Skinny Controller", a model would be a better fit.